# Integrating App Service with NAT gateway to get static outbound IP

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

1. Firstly, I integrate VNET with Azure App Service
2. In order to route traffic to VNet, I add WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL with value 1 in App service settings.
3. I created NATgateway and attached it to the subnet.
4. I also created a route and attached it to the subnet in that route, I gave the address prefix as VNET address space and for the Next hop type I selected virtual appliance and in Next hop address I add NAT gateway public IP.

Note: I used the below link for reference:
https://sakaldeep.com.np/1159/azure-nat-gateway-and-web-app-vnet-integration-to-get-static-outbound-ip

after doing all above steps and I checked with below command I didn't get NAT gateway IP as result
az webapp show --resource-group <group_name> --name <app_name> --query outboundIpAddresses --output tsv

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx)? It seems you issue is not related to Azure DevOps~

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service is a multi-tenant service. All App Service plans in the same deployment unit, and app instances that run in them, share the same set of virtual IP addresses. When you run

```
az webapp show --resource-group <group_name> --name <app_name> --query outboundIpAddresses --output tsv
```

you just get the Outbound IP Addresses Properties of your web app. You can find all possible outbound IP addresses for your app, regardless of pricing tiers, click **Properties** in your app's left-hand navigation. They are listed in the Additional Outbound IP Addresses field. The above outbound IP addresses will not change.

But if you send a request from your web app within a VNet over the internet, you should find the NAT gateway IP as the source.

For example, you could try to find the public IP from SSH (Linux app service) with
the command.

```
curl ipinfo.io/ip
```

[image]

Comment: can you explain a bit more about this? the process I followed is correct or not to get the static outbound IP using NAT gateway if correct how to find NAT gateway IP as the source. when I gave ping in cmd it will show app service outbound IP not a NAT gateway IP

Comment: The calls made by your app within the VNet to the internet will go out to the NAT Gateway IP. You can make calls to the internet from your app service console. Check my edit.